# How to evaluate an attributes and replace it in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to achieve the following (http://jsfiddle.net/EM8hr/2/), just as an example

```
<section ng-app="Myapp">
    <ul ng-controller="MainController">
        <li ng-repeat="link in links">
            {{link}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Angular:

```
Myapp = angular.module("Myapp", [])

Myapp.controller("MainController", function($scope){
  $scope.links = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy1WqQbqKpA"]
});

Myapp.directive("videolink", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.text(attrs.src.replace(/www\./gi,""))
        }
    }
});
```

But cannot achieve the desired response. I know this has to go with a link and scope attributes of the directive, but I couldn't quite figure out the correct manner of it. Can anyone assist? (http://jsfiddle.net/tRG4T/)

```
Myapp.directive("videolink", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        scope: {src:"@"},
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            return  attrs.src.replace(/www\./gi,"")
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply use a function to strip your urls, which will be called on every modification (in the link function, the data is not bound, so you will try to replace a string on something undefined)

The fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/EM8hr/5/

you could for example add a src attribute to your directive as in your second example and call it this way :

```
    <li ng-repeat="link in links">
        <videolink src='{{link}}'></videolink>
    </li>
```

then on the directive side, you could do something like this

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope:{src:"@"},
    replace:false,
    template:'{{stripW(src)}}',
    link:function(scope, elt,attr){
        scope.stripW=function(url){
             return url.replace(/www\./gi,"");   
        }
    }
}
```

you define in the scope a function to do what you want (here, strip the www part of the url) and you bind it in the template. When the url will be passed to the function, there will be a modification of the src, which will trigger the function, and replace your text properly

Have fun

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was aiming for, but I understood the mechanics of link/template/scope better through your reply. Thanks